# Ajax call to Django send email not responding

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm using Djrill to send emails from my Django application.

Using ajax, I call the view that handles the email sending as follows:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/sendmail&name="+name+"&receiver="+email+"&phone="+phone+"&address="+address,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(){
            console.log('done');
        }
    });
```

The views.py for this is:

```
def sendEmail(request):
    if 'receiver' in request.GET and request.GET['receiver']:
        name = request.GET['name']
        recv = request.GET['receiver']
        phone = request.GET['phone']
        address = request.GET['address']
        from django.core.mail import send_mail
        send_mail("Service name: "+name, "Phone Number: "+phone+" <br>Address: "+address, "<sender@example.com", [recv])
        return 'True Data'
    else:
        return 'False data'
```

Urls.py

```
url(r'^sendmail$', views.sendEmail, name='sendmail'),
```

The response to the ajax call gives a 404 error.

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL should be `sendmail?` instead of `sendmail&` in the request:

```
url: "/sendmail?name="+name+"&receiver="+email+"&phone="+phone+"&address="+address,
               ^ there
```

Otherwise, it is looking for an URL with the pattern `sendmail&name=(.+)`, which doesn't exist, obviously.

See [Query string structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) for more information (but I think it is also a typo from you)